# Ubuntu 18.04 using Netplan with dhcp and static DNS settings seems totally broken

Tags: dns, 18.04, dhcp, netplan

In Ubuntu 18.04 configured to use DHCP on a wired connection, there does not seem to be a setting to have it use static DNS settings. Netplan seems to have no setting equivalent to "ipv4.ignore-auto-dns yes" This would be equivalent of the commands:

```
nmcli connection modify ${ID} ipv4.ignore-auto-dns yes 
nmcli connection modify ${ID} ipv4.dns 'xx.xx.xx.10 xx.xx.xx.20' 
nmcli connection modify ${ID} ipv4.dns-search 'abc01.domain.com. abc02.domain.com.'
```

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 server or desktop edition?

Comment: Its server, but I expect desktop would be equally affected as they both use Netplan just with different renderers by default.  For instance, Im using NetworkManager with server to be consistent with Rhel and Centos servers in the environment.

Comment: OK, I've worked up a work around for this issue.  Ive supplied an example script that uses NetworkManager and tells systemd and Netplan the correct settings.

Comment: systemctl stop systemd-resolved  <br/>
    sed -i 's/#DNS=/DNS=10.10.11.22 10.10.11.23/' /etc/systemd/resolved.conf   <br/>
    sed -i 's/#Domains=/Domains=abc.domain.edu def.domain.edu' /etc/systemd/resolved.conf  <br/>
    systemctl start systemd-resolved  <br/>
    systemctl restart NetworkManager  <br/>
    netplan apply  <br/>
    reboot  <br/>

Comment: I can confirm that Ubuntu 18.04 Desktop completely ignores static DNS settings when DHCP is enabled.